# Multilevel dropdown menu in a django form

Tags: python, django, forms, list

Django beginner here.

I would like to create a 2-level dropdown menu in a django form. Something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvwJl.jpg

I would like to be able to fill a form field with strings 'A1', 'B3', 'C2' or whatever I choose from the dropdown menu.

I tried using a choice field in the model to create the choices for the form but I don't know how to turn this into a 2-level dropdown menu. Maybe there is a hint in the documentation but I was unable to find it...

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    POSITION_CHOICES = [
            ('A', 'A'),
            ('B', 'B'),
            ('C', 'C'),
        ]
"""
how do I specify the second level of choices here(1,2,3)?
also, the second level is always the same for A,B and C and I would like to avoid repeating code. 
"""

    position = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=POSITION_CHOICES)


# forms.py
from django import forms
from .models import Player

class PlayerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ('name', 'position',)


# views.py
from django.views import generic

class PlayerCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = Player
    form_class = PlayerForm
    template_name = 'player_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ### do I have to add anything here since the choices are hard-coded?
        ### form.instance.position = ???
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

'player_form.html' template.
Do I have to add anything to the template to make the multilevel dropdown menu appear?

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Create Player</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```